# Question about the Basis Extension Theorem proof: constructing an arbitrary spanning list $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ for an arbitrary vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm not sure I know how to best ask this question (which you can probably tell from the following text), but I'll give it a go.

I am currently reading "*Linear Algebra as an Introduction to Abstract Mathematics*". There is a proof presented in Chapter 5 known as the **Basis Extension Theorem**. This proof involves a sort of "iterative method" as you will see.

---

> *Basis Extension Theorem*: Every linearly independent list of vectors in a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ can be extended to a basis of $V$.

*Proof*: Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and that $(v_1, ..., v_m)$ is linearly independent. Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, there exists a list $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ of vectors that spans $V$. We wish to adjoin some of the $w_k$ to $(v_1, ..., v_m)$ in order to create a basis of $V$.

**Step 1.** If $w_1 \in \text{span}(v_1, ..., v_m)$, then let $\mathcal S = (v_1, ..., v_m)$. Otherwise, $\mathcal S = (v_1, ..., v_m, w_1)$.

**Step $k$**. If $w_k \in \text{span}(\mathcal S)$, then leave $\mathcal S$ unchanged. Otherwise, adjoin $w_k$ to $\mathcal S$.

After each step, the list $\mathcal S$ is still linearly independent since we only adjoined $w_k$ if $w_k$ was not in the span of the previous vectors. After $n$ steps, $w_k \in \text{span}(\mathcal S)$ for all $k = 1, 2, ..., n.$ Since $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ was a spanning list, $\mathcal S$ spans $V$ so that $\mathcal S$ is indeed a basis for $V$.

---

My question is related to the opening line that asserts the existence of $(w_1, ..., w_n)$.

My experience with proofs that require the "existence" of something else is primarily restricted to demonstrating that certain functions with particular properties exist. When going through these "function existence proofs", there are usually some clever *construction steps* that must be employed in order to demonstrate that such a function (exhibiting the desired properties) exists.

For the above proof, is there a *construction step* ***analog*** for the line asserting the existence of $(w_1, ..., w_m)$? Is the construction step (although explicitly omitted) as straight forward as $V=\text{span}(w_1, ..., w_n)$? And that's it?

I would think that more is required to create an arbitrary spanning list of vectors (though perhaps this is all implicitly carried out by the author)...but perhaps not. I guess because there are no "special properties" of the vector space $V$, the actual construction of the spanning vector list can be this...generic?

Thank you!

Edit: My major trouble with accepting this "generic" construction step is that I do not see how the spanning list can be chosen in a "finite" manner. There are an infinite number of vectors in a vector space (e.g. $\mathbb R^2$)...so you wouldn't be able to just create some iterative method of guessing what $w_1, w_2,...,$ and $w_n$ should be such that, at some point, $\text{span}(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) = V$.

Comment: I think the author simply uses as a definition of a finite dimensional space,  a space with a finite set of generators. He justs works with this finite set, which is  given by definition.

Comment: @Bernard so the definition in this case implicitly invokes a construction of a spanning set? That seems like you're cheating or something. To use "function existence proofs" as an example, why do I even need to prove the existence of such functions if I can just create a definition says "This is what function W does". Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't invoke implicitly any construction, but explicitly the existence., which is part of the data of the problem. Maybe you'll find that clearer if you know the French name of this result (I translate it): the *Incomplete basis theorem*.

Comment: This theorem simply says that, given a linearly independent set of vectors and any spanning set, you may pick vectors  in the spanning set that complete the independent set to form a basis.

Comment: @Bernard Given your responses, perhaps this is a better way of phrasing my question. If I know that "something exists" but I did not construct it, how can I directly USE it? That is to say, this entire proof strategy relies directly on ACCESS (and therefore specific knowledge) of the spanning list $(w_1, ..., w_n)$. Is "Existence of a spanning list" the same thing as "knowing specifically what $w_1, w_2, w_3, ...$ etc are"? I would think not.

Comment: Where's the problem in not knowing individually the $w_i$s? Did you never solve geometric problems in which, say, a right triangle was given, yet you didn't have to justify how you got the vertices?

Comment: @Bernard I suppose that is right...but for some reason I'm still getting tripped up. In your example of the right triangle, I would think that there is a general equation that I could impose which would force a relationship among the vertices such that they spatially align with one another in a way that guarantees the construction of an arbitrary right triangle. It is that sort of construction that I feel as though the spanning list lacks.

Comment: And you're reasoning with properties of sequence, say to show any convergent sequence is Cauchy, do you need the formula that defines the sequence?

Comment: Gaussian elimination together with a smart choice of vectors allows you to generate a spanning set in principle. If $\dim V=n$, choose $n$ vectors, form a column-matrix out of them and test its rank. If it is $n$, you are done. If it's not, discard the unneeded vectors and "smartly" choose new ones so that the rank increases at least by 1. Do this until rank is $n$.

Comment: @Bernard I think I get your point. Therefore, would this make the most sense in the context of my initial question? Let $A=\{\mathcal X: \text{span}(\mathcal X) = V\}$ where $\mathcal X$ is a finite list of vectors in $V$ and then I would just say that the list $(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) \in A$.

Comment: Introducing $A$ doesn't change much: now you can ask the same question of your set $A$ as you do of the individual $\mathcal X\in A$.